# jquery function not work in content master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to call the jquery in content master page but it does not work while in the content master page whereas it works on its own.

The code in Master page is

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="datetimepicker.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in Content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <img src="Styles/sms1.png" alt="not" />   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: You can change your master and content page as per the recommendation in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the piece of code below in your master page, Your script is being inserted into the `ContentPlaceHolder1` but the jquery is being loaded after the script. Thats why its not working since the script should be injected after the jquery loaded.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can change your `Master` page and `Content` page as below to make sure, the script is injected after the jquery script.

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="datetimepicker.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="script" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Content Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <img src="Styles/sms1.png" alt="not" /> 
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="script" runat="server">  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

If you look at the above code, another `ContentPlaceHolder` for the script is created in the master page after the jquery and other scripts and the content page script is moved into this new place holder.

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried, I will check?

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <img src="Styles/sms1.png" alt="not" />   

</asp:Content>

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="script" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
            showsTime: true,
            ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
            daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
            align: "BR",
            electric: false,
            singleClick: false,
            displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
            button: ".next()"
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>

Comment: What about Master page?

Comment: <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Comment: </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="script" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Comment: It should work, Build your code, refresh the page and check again.

Comment: If you use, google chrome, open the developer tools and check the console for any errors

Comment: sir i use this code when click on img then open the datepicker but in my code this is not open

Comment: I found another issue on your script. Change this line `$("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>")` to `$("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>")`. I have added `#`

Comment: Click the textbox and not the image as you are passing the textbox id

Comment: if i run the same code without master page then it will run

Comment: sory for wasting your time

Comment: sir can u guide me for future ..i am complete my bscs ....now what i do...

Comment: Yeah sure, you can message here to contact me. When you go to the answer above, there will be up and down arrows left to my answer. You can see the tick icon below the down arrow when you hover the mouse there and you can click the tick to accept the answer.

Comment: You have to click the tick icon for this and not by comment :- scroll up to top of the answer, there will be up and down arrows left to my answer. Or you can see number 0. Below the number 0, you can see a down arrow. If you bring the mouse cursor to the down arrow and a bit down again, you can see a tick icon which you have to click to accept the answer.